# Netgear Smart Connect WPS

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wps

I recently bought a Netgear Nighthawk R7000 router, and it comes with a feature called Netgear Smart Connect. When this is enabled, the administration pannel disables the WPS settings area.

I've noticed I can't actually turn off WPS completely on this router, but does Smart Connect disable the pin mode of WPS?

(It doesn't seem like Smart Connect on the R8000 is the same as on the R7000)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Netgear support. You cannot turn off WPS, but only disable the pin when Smart Connect is off.